# find all points $(a,b,c)$ for which the the spheres $(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}+(z-c)^{2}=1$ and $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$ intercect orthogonally

Tags: partial-derivative

find all points $(a,b,c)$  in space for which the the spheres $(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}+(z-c)^{2}= 1$ and $x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=1$ will intersect orthogonally

I used the fact that the  dot products of the gradients must be zero but I got equations which yielded wrong solutions so  please help.

Comment: Do you mean $(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}+(z-c)^{2}=1$?

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot

Comment: Then you should edit your post.

Comment: Show your work if you’d like someone to point out where you went wrong instead of just being fed a solution. “I got equations which yielded wrong solutions” doesn’t tell us much. Maybe you set up the correct equations but made a mistake in solving them. There’s no way for anyone else to tell without seeing the details of your work.

Comment: I found out that the equations where correct but I forgot to include one of the sphere equations. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the rotational symmetry of the problem, whether or not the two spheres intersect orthogonally depends solely on the distance of $(a,b,c)$ from the origin. So we can simplify the problem by assuming $(a,b,c)$ is on the positive  $x$-axis, so that $a > 0$ and $b = c = 0$, and then determining which values of $a$ work.

The spheres intersect when $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 = (x-a)^2 + y^2 + z^2$. Subtracting the two equations leads to $a(2x - a) = 0$, so that $x = {a \over 2}$.

They intersect orthogonally if the gradients are orthogonal at the points of intersection. So at points of intersection we require
$$<2x, 2y, 2z> \cdot <2x - 2a, 2y, 2z> = 0$$
This leads to 
$$4(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) = 4ax$$
Since $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$ and $x = {a \over 2}$, we get that
$4 = 2a^2$, so that $a = \sqrt{2}$.

We conclude that the spheres intersect orthogonally if the distance of the center $(a,b,c)$ from the origin is equal to $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, given two spheres below

$$(x-a)^{2}+(y-b)^{2}+(z-c)^{2}=p^2$$
$$x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}=q^2$$

In order for them to intersect orthogonally, the centers of the two spheres and their intersection point form a right triangle, which means that the point $(a, b,c)$ should be at the distance

$$d=\sqrt{p^2+q^2}$$

from the origin, thus, in a sphere with the radius $d$. Given $p=q=1$ in the question, $(a,b,c)$ satisfies

$$a^2+b^2+c^2=2$$